# Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0 - Network is unreachable

Tags: android, proxy, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build my first ever app in Android Studio, but keep getting the error below when building with Gradle.

```
Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
Required by:
    project :app
 > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.
    > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
          > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.1.0/appcompat-v7-26.1.0.pom'.
                   > Network is unreachable (connect failed)
```

I am behind a proxy, which could be blocking the connection, but when checking the connection (in Settings > Proxy) with the URL in the error message, it says `Connection Succesful`.

**Top-level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

Is it something related to the proxy? How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Proxy might be blocking SSL connections. You need to download SSL certificates on your system.
Simplest way to do is, switch off your proxy and then build. And then it should work.